# How to skip the generation of factory and implementation classes when using openapi-generator?

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I am using [OpenApi generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) version 6.6.0 but working with the [Gradle generator plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin).
I am using the jaxrs-jersey server generator have looked through the documentation for a way to turn off generation of the factory **(*Factory.java)** and implementation **(*Impl.java)** classes but can not find anything in the documentation to achieve this.

I see that, it is possible to somewhat achieve this, if one does not generate the API classes, however I'd like to generate them.

Is this a possibility?

Below is my `openApiGenerate` task config:

```
openApiGenerate{
    generatorName = "jaxrs-jersey"
    cleanupOutput = true
    inputSpec = "$project.swaggerFile"
    outputDir = "$project.buildSrcRoot"
    apiPackage = "$project.apiPackage"
    invokerPackage = "$project.rootPackage"
    modelPackage = "$project.modelPackage"
    generateModelTests = false
    globalProperties = [
            apis: "false",
            models: "",
            modelDocs: "false",
    ]
    configOptions = [
        dateLibrary: "java8",
        developerOrganizationUrl: "https://my-org.com",
        hideGenerationTimestamp: "true",
        useJakartaEe: "true"
    ]

}
```